How to remote control desktop computer on the other side of the room?
I am rethinking my home office and want to get my desktop PC tower out of sight.  I will redo my desk and cabinetry and was thinking about putting the PC on the far side of the room, which is is about 4 meters or 13 feet wall to wall.
I was wondering if there was a way to connect my keyboard, mouse, headset and the odd peripheral to a device that would send this input to another similar device on the other side of the room and into the PC ports. Ideal scenario would be to have one box sitting on my desk with a power on and reset button and the USB ports.
I am not even talking about video output - I know I will have to use one of those extra long DisplayPort or HDMI cables for each screen.
Does such solution exists?

If you are planning to use an extra long cable for video output, why dont you use an extra long usb 3 cable from the pc to your table and connect a usb hub where you can plug all the usbs. to turn on the pc simply go to bios and check if there is an option to turn on your pc with a keyboard button or a combination. this is just a simple solution without any expensive or complicated hardware.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
